# Updating CSS with SCSS using Jekyll

Tags: css, sass, jekyll

Decided to try Louis Rassaby Theme. I am still new with sass/scss using Jekyll. I am unable to update main.css with _filename.scss files. I assumed that Jekyll would do it automatically every time I do `jekyll serve`.

I forked theme from https://github.com/lrassaby/lrassaby.github.io.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the theme you forked uses Gulp npm packages to manage its asset pipeline, and included in that is [a step that processes Sass files](https://github.com/lrassaby/lrassaby.github.io/blob/master/gulpfile.js#L43). From the documentation, it seems like you can run `npx bundle exec gulp` to serve the site locally, and that should watch the Sass files for changes—just make sure you're including new imports in `src/styles/` and including import statements for them in your `src/styles/main.scss` file, which is getting output as `assets/css/main.css`.

This will not work with Jekyll's standard build/serve flow, which uses a Ruby gem to handle the Sass processing and requires you to specify a folder for storing Sass imports in your Jekyll config and then include those imports in a file that it will process ([see documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/assets/#sassscss)). To change it so that it's using Jekyll's build process, you'd need to move all of your imports from [the current Sass folder](https://github.com/lrassaby/lrassaby.github.io/blob/master/src/styles) to one you've defined in your Jekyll config file (or simply point to this existing folder in your config, though you'd also have to make sure it's included in Jekyll processing), then move the `main.scss` file into your `assets/css/` folder. That might break your existing asset pipeline, though, unless you remove the Sass processing step from it.

Comment: Thank you, I tried and struggled with it for awhile. Turned out that Gulp 4.0 is incompatible with Jekyll and needed to be downgraded to Gulp 3.9.1 and now it is working.